# Display database result as XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml

I have a simple SQL query, i want to query the database and return the result as XML. I used the key word `for XML`, but it says that XML is not a valid syntax.
 HELP

```
using (SqlConnection c= new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            string s= "select * from Doctor for XML";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s,c))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    ad.Fill(t); // IT SAYS XML IS NOT A VALID SYNTAX
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you are using the wrong class for this task. Search about the method `ExecuteXmlReader` of `SqlCommand`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataAdapter.Fill()` method to fill query results into a `DataTable` and then convert to xml.

Here MSDN link for [DataTable.WriteXml() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx)

```
using (SqlConnection c= new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    string s= "select * from Doctor"; //remove the for xml

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s,c))
    {
         using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
         {
            DataTable dt;
            ad.Fill(dt); 

            //Use DataTable.WriteXml() method 
            //dt.WriteXml(parameters);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, i first want to grab the XML and thereafter populate the grid using the XML data

Comment: You can do it. dt.WriteXml() method does not change DataTable (dt).

Comment: Please visit the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx) link above and there are a few overloads for the method. For example you can write DataTable as an xml file or as a string using a StringWriter() etc.

Answer (score 0):

You dont you fill the data into a dataset and convert it into a XML document ?
wont that work for you  ?
Check the following posts

[Dataset -> XML Document - Load DataSet into an XML Document - C#.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667063/dataset-xml-document-load-dataset-into-an-xml-document-c-net)

[Convert Dataset to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384014/convert-dataset-to-xml)

Comment: Well, i still don't understand how to retrieve XML, and display it on the grid. (I'm a beginner)

Comment: What kind of application are you working on ? Why dont you directly bind the dataset to the grid rather than converting it into an XML ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executexmlreader.aspx) instead.